# Installing WinPcap on Windows 10

Tags: installation, winpcap

i whant to instal winpcap on window 10 but i get error

> --------------------------- WinPcap 4.1.3 Setup --------------------------- This version of Windows is not supported by WinPcap 4.1.3. The installation will be aborted.
>   --------------------------- OK    ---------------------------

what i can do

Comment: what version of windows are you trying to install it on?

Comment: i use window 10 professional

Comment: oohh tnks i instl winpcap vision 4.1.3 is not meet for window 10 i download win10pca  phttp://www.win10pcap.org/ its solve my ploblem tnks for you answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [Npcap](https://nmap.org/npcap/) is the best alternative.
It works on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's because you already installed Npcap, you need to unistall it first and then install WinPcap